# Invoke a Function in Action class with href in struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I am trying to load a file on click of a href on my JSP page. The file is not stored within the directory of the web server. Therefore, on clicking the href I may need to invoke an action which would read the file, copy it to the webserver in a temporary directory and then show to the user. (The file could be msword, pdf, html etc).

I have been able to find how an action can be invoked in struts 2 using . But how can this be achieved in struts 1.2 ?

Only other solution I can think of is redirecting to another JSP page and then invoking its action classes to do the rest. But is it possible to call an action directly from an href ?

Comment: Why not just stream it back?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Here's how I call my Struts action from href links -

```
<a href="YourActionsClass.do?method=execute">some link text</a>
```

and in your struts-config.xml add

```
parameter=method
```

execute is the method inside your action class which extends org.apache.struts.action.Action